# Реализация плавающего поп-ап окна

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, popup

Как реализовать pop-up окно, которое будет появляться по заданным координатам (к примеру, по центру) и, самое главное, будет **НЕ** с фиксированным позиционированием.

Вот [пример реализации](http://teanote.ru/20/) такого окна.

Answer (score 1):

Если интересует устройство простейшего окна, которое всегда позиционируется, например, по центру, то оно ниже. Как его наполнять, показывать и скрывать, автор может уже решить сам.

```css
#popup
{  
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  Window
</div>
```

Если же нужны готовые решения, то их немало.
Пара хороших ссылок:
[http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/](http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/#)

http://jquerymodal.com/

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример

1) Подключаем необходимы библиотеки

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

2)При нажатии на кнопку открываем модальное окно

3) С помощью js делаем его `draggable`

```js
$("#myModal").draggable({
  handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Settings</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Settings</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: что-то сниппет ничего не показывает

Comment: в фидле какие-то совсем старые версии библиотек

Comment: Спасибо, но мне, чтобы разобраться во всех этих линках уйдет ужасно много времени... Спасибо все равно!

Comment: @Grundy изменил на свежие библиотеки , теперь работает